# PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin - Camera Close

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We are developing an application in which we need to use the barcode scanner plugin. The scanner is working fine.

Our case is that we want to scan multiple items and then at some point, we want the user to close the scanner manually through a close icon.

How is that possible?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible without modifying the source of the plugin